# Redshift - Finding difference between rows for the same id

Tags: amazon-redshift, window-functions

I am trying to find the difference in value across rows and have built the below

Data:

```
cust_id,sales
cust_1,30
cust_1,43
cust_1,4
cust_2,5
cust_2,8
```

I have built the below:

```
select cust_id,sales, sales - lag(sales) over (order by cust_id) as change from table;
```

This returns the below output:

```
cust_id,sales, difference
cust_1,30,13
cust_1,43,-39
cust_1,4,1
cust_2,5,3
cust_2,8,
```

How do I change the above output to only calculate difference if the cust_id is same and leave it blank if the cust_id changes. Using Redshift.

Comment: `partition by cust_id order by sales`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you that helped. Could you also help me on how I could find the average of difference by cust_id on the above.

Comment: @scottmartin, could you share the final result you're trying to achieve.